# Host controls in Windows Forms DataGridView Cells in C#?

Tags: c#, datagridview, user-controls, datetimepicker, datagridviewtextboxcell

I have some code copy from msdn

```
public class CalendarColumn : DataGridViewColumn
{
  public CalendarColumn() : base(new CalendarCell())
{
}

public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
{
    get
    {
        return base.CellTemplate;
    }
    set
    {
        // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell. 
        if (value != null && 
            !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
        {
            throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
        }
        base.CellTemplate = value;
    }
}
}

public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{

public CalendarCell()
    : base()
{
    // Use the short date format. 
    this.Style.Format = "d";
}

public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object 
    initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
{
    // Set the value of the editing control to the current cell value. 
    base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, 
        dataGridViewCellStyle);
    CalendarEditingControl ctl = 
        DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
    // Use the default row value when Value property is null. 
    if (this.Value == null)
    {
        ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.DefaultNewRowValue;
    }
    else
    {
        ctl.Value = (DateTime)this.Value;
    }
}

public override Type EditType
{
    get
    {
        // Return the type of the editing control that CalendarCell uses. 
        return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
    }
}

public override Type ValueType
{
    get
    {
        // Return the type of the value that CalendarCell contains. 

        return typeof(DateTime);
    }
}

public override object DefaultNewRowValue
{
    get
    {
        // Use the current date and time as the default value. 
        return DateTime.Now;
    }
}
}

 class CalendarEditingControl : DateTimePicker, IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
DataGridView dataGridView;
private bool valueChanged = false;
int rowIndex;

public CalendarEditingControl()
{
    this.Format = DateTimePickerFormat.Short;
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlFormattedValue  
// property. 
public object EditingControlFormattedValue
{
    get
    {
        return this.Value.ToShortDateString();
    }
    set
    {            
        if (value is String)
        {
            try
            {
                // This will throw an exception of the string is  
                // null, empty, or not in the format of a date. 
                this.Value = DateTime.Parse((String)value);
            }
            catch
            {
                // In the case of an exception, just use the  
                // default value so we're not left with a null 
                // value. 
                this.Value = DateTime.Now;
            }
        }
    }
}

// Implements the  
// IDataGridViewEditingControl.GetEditingControlFormattedValue method. 
public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
    DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
{
    return EditingControlFormattedValue;
}

// Implements the  
// IDataGridViewEditingControl.ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl method. 
public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
    DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
{
    this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;
    this.CalendarForeColor = dataGridViewCellStyle.ForeColor;
    this.CalendarMonthBackground = dataGridViewCellStyle.BackColor;
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlRowIndex  
// property. 
public int EditingControlRowIndex
{
    get
    {
        return rowIndex;
    }
    set
    {
        rowIndex = value;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey  
// method. 
public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
    Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
{
    // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
    switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
    {
        case Keys.Left:
        case Keys.Up:
        case Keys.Down:
        case Keys.Right:
        case Keys.Home:
        case Keys.End:
        case Keys.PageDown:
        case Keys.PageUp:
            return true;
        default:
            return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit  
// method. 
public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
{
    // No preparation needs to be done.
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
// .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
{
    get
    {
        return false;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
// .EditingControlDataGridView property. 
public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
{
    get
    {
        return dataGridView;
    }
    set
    {
        dataGridView = value;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
// .EditingControlValueChanged property. 
public bool EditingControlValueChanged
{
    get
    {
        return valueChanged;
    }
    set
    {
        valueChanged = value;
    }
}

// Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
// .EditingPanelCursor property. 
public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
{
    get
    {
        return base.Cursor;
    }
}

protected override void OnValueChanged(EventArgs eventargs)
{
    // Notify the DataGridView that the contents of the cell 
    // have changed.
    valueChanged = true;
    this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
    base.OnValueChanged(eventargs);
}
}
```

I am getting datetimepicker in my datagridview...., Now in place of dateTimePicker i want to use UserControl TextBox....., I try but i don't get exact answer....I show my code below
cisControls.txtDate is my userControl TextBox

```
     public CalendarColumn()
        : base(new CalendarCell())
    { }
    public override DataGridViewCell CellTemplate
    {
        get
        {
            return base.CellTemplate;
        }
        set
        {
            // Ensure that the cell used for the template is a CalendarCell. 
            if (value != null &&
                !value.GetType().IsAssignableFrom(typeof(CalendarCell)))
            {
                throw new InvalidCastException("Must be a CalendarCell");
            }
            base.CellTemplate = value;
        }
    }
}
public class CalendarCell : DataGridViewTextBoxCell
{
    ciscontrols.txtDate ct = new ciscontrols.txtDate();
    public CalendarCell()
        : base()
    {
       // this.Style.Format = ct.Text;
    }
    public override void InitializeEditingControl(int rowIndex, object initialFormattedValue, DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        base.InitializeEditingControl(rowIndex, initialFormattedValue, dataGridViewCellStyle);
        CalendarEditingControl ct1 = DataGridView.EditingControl as CalendarEditingControl;
        //if (this.Value == null)
        //{
        //    ct1.Text = ct1.Text;
        //}
        //else
        //{
        //    // ct1.Text = Convert.ToString(this.Value);
        //}

    }
    public override Type EditType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
        }
    }
    public override Type ValueType
    {
        get
        {
            return typeof(CalendarEditingControl);
            //return typeof(DateTime);
        }
    }
    public override object DefaultNewRowValue
    {

        get
       {
            return ct.Text;
        }
    }
}
class CalendarEditingControl : ciscontrols.txtDate,IDataGridViewEditingControl
{
    DataGridView datagridview;
    private bool valuechanged = false;
    int rowIndex;
    ciscontrols.txtDate ct = new ciscontrols.txtDate();
    public CalendarEditingControl()
    {
        this.Text = "";
    }
    public object EditingControlFormattedValue
    {
        get
         {
            return ct.Text;
        }
        set
        {
            ct.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
    public object GetEditingControlFormattedValue(
   DataGridViewDataErrorContexts context)
    {
        return EditingControlFormattedValue;
    }
    public void ApplyCellStyleToEditingControl(
    DataGridViewCellStyle dataGridViewCellStyle)
    {
        this.Font = dataGridViewCellStyle.Font;

    }
    public int EditingControlRowIndex
    {
        get
        {
            return rowIndex;
        }
        set
        {
            rowIndex = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.EditingControlWantsInputKey  
    // method. 
    public bool EditingControlWantsInputKey(
        Keys key, bool dataGridViewWantsInputKey)
    {
        // Let the DateTimePicker handle the keys listed. 
        switch (key & Keys.KeyCode)
        {
            case Keys.Left:
            case Keys.Up:
            case Keys.Down:
            case Keys.Right:
            case Keys.Home:
            case Keys.End:
            case Keys.PageDown:
            case Keys.PageUp:
                return true;
            default:
                return !dataGridViewWantsInputKey;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl.PrepareEditingControlForEdit  
    // method. 
    public void PrepareEditingControlForEdit(bool selectAll)
    {
        // No preparation needs to be done.
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange property. 
    public bool RepositionEditingControlOnValueChange
    {
        get
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlDataGridView property. 
    public DataGridView EditingControlDataGridView
    {
        get
        {
            return datagridview;
        }
       set
        {
            datagridview = value;
       }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingControlValueChanged property. 
    public bool EditingControlValueChanged
    {
        get
        {
            return valuechanged;
        }
        set
        {
            valuechanged = value;
        }
    }

    // Implements the IDataGridViewEditingControl 
    // .EditingPanelCursor property. 
    public Cursor EditingPanelCursor
    {
        get
        {
            return base.Cursor;
        }
    }
    protected override void OnTextChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        valuechanged = true;
        this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        //this.EditingControlDataGridView.NotifyCurrentCellDirty(true);
        base.OnTextChanged(e);
    }

}
```

Comment: There is too much code for people to try to help you. Show only your relevant code.